# How to make custom graphical package installer

Tags: installation, package, wizard

i have wonder if there is any way to create custom installation wizard and add some graphics to it rather than traditional installation wizard that came with visual studio
i am look forward to something like modern setups like
[MS Office installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntQUt.png) or [Grammarly installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAptb.png).

Comment: Have you found a solution? Here is my similar question on Software Recommendations SE: [Simple installer-maker for minimal and graphical setup](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/84708/6389)